# jquery mobile button taps getting queued then processed later

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating a specialized calculator app with jquery mobile that has a lot of buttons.

My issue is when users tap buttons faster than they can be processed, sometimes taps get queued only to show up as a double tap the next time the button is tapped. A user hits buttons "1", "2", "3" and "4", "1234" should be displayed in another element. Instead you might see "134". And when you tap the "2" again, the display reads "13422". You can tap any number of other keys in the meantime, each getting processed, but the next time you hit "2" the tap event fires twice.

I capture all button taps, then process them based on a data-tag attribute.

```
    $('button').tap(function (event) {
    var tag = $(this).attr("data-tag")

    switch (tag){
       case "1":
       \\ do stuff
       break;

       case "2":
       //do stuff
       break;

            case "3":
       //do stuff
       break;
     }  
    });
```

I tried disabling the button during processing and re-enabling them later like this,

```
     $('button').tap(function (event) {


          $(this).prop('disabled', true).button('refresh');


        // process the taps


         $(this).prop('disabled', false).button('refresh');


    });
```

but this doesn't fix the problem.

How do I get all queued events to process without this strange trigger of a second tap?

Comment: try `vclick` instead of `tap`, as mobile browsers delay processing `tap` events 300ms.

Comment: I get the same issue with `vclick. Incidentally, on ios devices the problem always happens with the first button if a second button is tapped before the first one is processed.  ie. hitting '1' '2' always displays as '112' if the '2' is tapped before '1' is processed--j.k.

Comment: Try `.off('tap').on('tap', function ()`

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. I put a `event.preventDefault();` after I pick up the event.

```
    $('button').tap(function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         // do stuff
    )};
```

This prevents the doubling effect.

The only problem, is that you have to use tap because `event.preventDefault()` keeps vclick from working on a computer instead of a tap device.